# Does Android WebView loadUrl supports ipv6 adresses

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, ipv6, mjpeg

Does Android WebView loadUrl supports ipv6 literals?

I'm trying to get mjpg stream inside WebView widget.

For me something like: 
`webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.8.173:9030/stream.mjpg")`

 works fine. But when i try: 
`webView.loadUrl("http://[fe80::e749:69cc:3f0e:b0e3]:9030/stream.mjpg")` 
WebView shows ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT in WebView widget in app. 
 Is there any way to make it work? I need it to work on ipv6 in the final version.

I'm using Raspberry Pi with raspicam as mjpg server.

Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...
```

WebView widget code

```
val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webStreamView)
webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
webView.settings.userAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 Mobile Safari/537.36" // still nothing
webView.loadUrl("http://[fe80::e749:69cc:3f0e:b0e3]:9030/stream.mjpg")
```

Comment: When you say "throws", do you mean it shows an error message in the `WebView` itself? Or do you literally mean that it throws an exception from `loadUrl()`? If the latter, could you update your question with the complete stack trace?

Comment: It shows error in WebView itself, sorry about that.